# How to use retrive data in Firebase by using for loop?

Tags: angularjs, for-loop, foreach, firebase

So I have an register controller to check if the user's registration code is valid. In the SignUp function, I have a global variable called validGroupCode to mark if the code is valid. I set it true if the input group code match with the existing code in Firebase. The console's log shows the validGroupCode is true inside the forEach, however, in the console's log, the validGroupCode is always false outside the forEach() function. It turns out forEach() is a sync operation, so how can i use for loop to retrieve the data?

```
// Register controller
.controller('RegisterCtrl', ['$scope', '$firebaseArray', '$location', 'CommonProp', '$firebaseAuth', function($scope, $firebaseArray, $location, CommonProp, $firebaseAuth) {
$scope.signUp = function() {

    var firebaseObj = new Firebase("xxxx.com/");

    var firebaseGroupObj = new Firebase("hxxxebaseio.com/Groups");

    var validGroupCode = false;

    // Sign up implementation 
    if (!$scope.regForm.$invalid) {

        // var groupQuery = firebaseGroupObj.orderByChild('code').equalTo(groupcode);
        firebaseGroupObj.on("value", function(allGroupCodes){
            allGroupCodes.forEach(function(codeValue) {
                var existingCode = codeValue.child("code").val();

                if (existingCode === groupcode){

                    validGroupCode = true;

                    if(email && password && validGroupCode) {
                        auth.$createUser({email, password})
                            .then(function(userData) {
                                // add user
                            });
                    }
                }        
            });

        });
        if(!validGroupCode){
            console.log("Group Code is not correct");
        }
    }    
};
```

}])

Comment: I think I figured out how to do it. To prevent the synchronize, I just used the $loaded() function, put all above into this one, then everything works great! $scope.data.$loaded()
  .then(function() {
    console.log($scope.data);
  })
  .catch(function(err) {
    console.error(err);
  });

Answer (score 0):

for is an async operation. if you want the result to be sync to the next code, it should be used with

```
// Register controller
.controller('RegisterCtrl', ['$scope', '$firebaseArray', '$location', 'CommonProp', '$firebaseAuth', function($scope, $firebaseArray, $location, CommonProp, $firebaseAuth) {
$scope.signUp = function() {

    var firebaseObj = new Firebase("xxxx.com/");

    var firebaseGroupObj = new Firebase("hxxxebaseio.com/Groups");

    var validGroupCode = false;

    // Sign up implementation 
    if (!$scope.regForm.$invalid) {

        // var groupQuery = firebaseGroupObj.orderByChild('code').equalTo(groupcode);
        firebaseGroupObj.on("value", function(allGroupCodes){

           /////For instead of forEach, for sync operation,
           /////so the if(!validGroupCode) will come after the for loop

           for(var index in allGroupCodes){
                var codeValue = allGroupCodes[index];
                var existingCode = codeValue.child("code").val();

                if (existingCode === groupcode){

                    validGroupCode = true;

                    if(email && password && validGroupCode) {
                        auth.$createUser({email, password})
                            .then(function(userData) {
                                // add user
                            });
                    }
                }        
            });
        }
        if(!validGroupCode){
            console.log("Group Code is not correct");
        }
    }    
};
```

Comment: thanks, Lior! this makes sense. But Firebase uses forEach to retrieve to data from the Datasnapshot, and I could not figure out how to use for Loop to accomplish it. I tried your code, but it told me codeValue.child just not a function.